# How to add existing user from the current site to a particular group using c#?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to use people picker control to list all existing users.Then i want add these users to a particular group. Currently the logic is to specify a new name and the user is getting added to AD.  But should change the logic so that it can support FBA users too, for that i have to change the UI to place a People Editor control instead of the text field so that the user can select an existing user from the current site.

```
  using (SPWeb oWebsite = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb("Website_URL"))
{
SPGroupCollection collGroups = oWebsite.Groups;
foreach (SPGroup oGroup in collGroups)
{
    foreach(SPUser oUser in oGroup.Users)
    {
       //code
    }
}
}
```

Please help me to get all users regardless of group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `PeopleEditor.CommaSeparatedAccounts` to get the string array of users specified in the people editor. Then loop through the array and do `web.EnsureUser` add finally add user to the group you want.

Comment: ok thanks.Is there any method to get all sp users in the site without iterating all groups?

Comment: Yes SPWeb.SiteUsers gives all users that belong to site collection.

Comment: Sorry, disn't realize that you were using OpenWeb inside, deleted my EDIT

Answer (score 0):

> **SPWeb.AllUsers**
>
> **SPWeb.Users**

You can also try the above properties to browse through the list of users.